# Creating a Varray

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a homework problem and I am stuck on part B.  I have completed part A with no problem but keep getting an error for part B.

A. Define a user-defined object type data type named phone_type with attributes COUNTRY_CODE, AREA_CODE and PHONE_NUMBER.

B.Define a user-defined VARRAY data type named Phone_List_type as an array of size three of the type phone_type.

Answer for A:

```
CREATE TYPE phone_type AS OBJECT (country_code Number, area_code Number, phone_number Number);
```

Result:  Type phone_type compiled

Answer for B.

```
CREATE TYPE phone_list_type AS VARRAY(3) of phone_type;
```

> Error Message: Name is already in use in exsisting object

Answer (score 0):

Try and DROP the phone_list_type before you (re)create it.  The problem arises
when you have already compiled the code that defines your type, and you want to change it (the code/definition) eg

```
 SQL> CREATE TYPE phone_type AS OBJECT (
  2    country_code Number
  3  , area_code Number
  4  , phone_number Number
  5  );
  6  /

Type PHONE_TYPE compiled

SQL> CREATE TYPE phone_list_type AS VARRAY(3) of phone_type;
  2  /

Type PHONE_LIST_TYPE compiled

SQL> CREATE TYPE phone_list_type AS VARRAY(3) of phone_type;
  2  /

Error starting at line : 1 in command -
CREATE TYPE phone_list_type AS VARRAY(3) of phone_type;
Error report -
ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object
00955. 00000 -  "name is already used by an existing object"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Oracle does not just "overwrite" the existing TYPE definition.  Now, you can drop the type and use your new definition:

```
SQL> drop type phone_list_type;

Type PHONE_LIST_TYPE dropped.

SQL> CREATE TYPE phone_list_type AS VARRAY(3) of phone_type;
  2  /

Type PHONE_LIST_TYPE compiled
```

If DROP TYPE ... does not work, you can also FORCE it
(see [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/drop_type.htm#LNPLS99989)).

Answer (score 0):

Use `CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE` instead of `CREATE TYPE`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE phone_list_type AS VARRAY(3) of phone_type;
```